# How to implement Autocomplete like Google with dynamic request parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery plugin [Autocomplete like Google](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#visibleLimit) for a form field `foo`:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        source : [{
            url:"/my/ajax/controller/foo?data[name]=%QUERY%",
            type:'remote'
        }],  
    });
});
```

The URI `/my/ajax/controller/foo?data[name]=%QUERY%` calls the database service (that executes a statement like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name LIKE %name%`), prepaires the data, and provides a simple array like `['qwer', 'asdf', 'yxcv']`.

Now I want to add autocomplete to another field (`bar`). The difference is, that it needs the *current* value of the `foo` for filtering, since the target SQL query looks like `SELECT * FROM bar WHERE number JOIN foo ON bar.foo_name = foo.name WHERE number LIKE %number% AND foo.name = foo_name`. Here is, how I tried to implement it:

```
$(function() {
    $("#bar").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        valueKey:'number',
        source : [{
            url:"/my/ajax/controller/bar?data[number]=%QUERY%&data[foo_name]=" + $('#foo').val(),
            type:'remote'
        }],  
    });
});
```

But the value of `foo` is read only one time -- when the page is loaded. That means, the changes and the current value are ignored then. I tried to pass a callback instead of the URL, but it didn't work.

**How to get "Autocomplete like Google" working with dynamically changing fields?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#bar").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        source : [
            function(q,add){
                $.getJSON("/my/ajax/controller/bar?data[number]=" + q + "&data[foo_name]=" + $('#foo').val(), function(resp) {
                    add(resp);
                })
        }],  
    });
});
```